# Maven parent pom's bom - not getting the version number of dependency in child pom

Tags: java, maven

I have a child pom which has got a parent pom, parent pom has got a bom entry, bom has got several relevant dependencies with proper version number. Now I want to use few of dependencies which are available in bom.
This is the basic structure -

child pom --> parent pom +  bom with scope provided -- there is no version number here

bom is another pom which has got relevant dependencies, now when I try to access any dependency which are inside bom, I get version number exception- dependencies.dependency.version .jar is missing. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

parent pom has got bom entry as dependency - bom

Comment: Is the BOM dependency defined in the parent pom's dependencyManagment section?

Comment: show parent pom + bom

Comment: Yes, bom is part of parent pom,like this

Comment: Yes, bom is part of parent pom,like this
--parent pom
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0-RC-1</version><packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent-pom</name>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
 <groupId>abc</groupId>
 <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
 <version>${bom.version}</version>
 <type>pom</type>
 <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

Comment: -- bom has got lot of dependencies
These dependencies I want to use in child pom, how can I use